# Rewrite or duplicate answer in a new question?

Tags: support

There is this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/148426/44370) about extracting *section 9* api "manpages" from the kernel sources. The question is on hold for being unclear. If someone doesn't know that the *coreutils* or the *kernel* manpages are extracted/generated in such a way, well content discovery is not obvious. It helps for instance if the person asks himself/herself if `ls -1` (that's one) appears or not in the manpages. No [seriously](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/111975/44370).

I have made a cautious edit to the original question. My question here is is there value in completely rewriting this to remove all dependency related stuff or should I make a new very precise question such as "How do you exactly generate the section 9 kernel manpages" and duplicate the answer I contributed? I think I should edit the original question very liberally but is that recommended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there aren't any other answers (well, other than FaheemMitha telling you the package name), you're not editing the foundation out of under someone else's answer.

So, I'd say, edit boldly.

Comment: And why am I writing a SE answer on my phone from the AMV room at Otakon? Something wrong there...

Comment: I agree w/ deroberts, edit boldly. You've been on the site long enough to exercise good judgement about the kernel of a good question, so expand it as you see fit.

Comment: Thank you(both)! Indeed I wouldn't contemplate it if it were self-promotional. I've been intellectually rewarded anyway. There is no need for me to second guess myself that much on this - it's an _edit_. Use common sense, and pay attention to community feedback. p.s. re Otakon, ah, "Protoculture"!